# Where to get Linux Kernel '4.15.0-1053-oem' for Lenovo ThinkPad P1 Gen 2?

Tags: drivers, kernel, lenovo, thinkpad, microphone

I'm looking for a specific Linux kernel built by Lenovo: '4.15.0-1053-oem', as detailed in this Ubuntu certification: https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201908-27280

My Dolby microphone does not work because there are no open-source drivers available. I'm guessing the OEM kernel would probably have this compiled specifically for this hardware, however my laptop did not ship with OEM Ubuntu. I'm wondering whether Lenovo has a package archive of kernels you could wget or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The -oem branch of the kernel is used by the [Ubuntu Kernel Team](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel).

Take a look at [their wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/OEMKernel) for a lot of good information.

Basically, OEM kernels are temporary workarounds for new OEM hardware *until the next stock kernel is created*. In other words, the features of an 18.04 OEM kernel should have been rolled into stock 18.10, 19.04, 19.10, etc. newer kernels. There are no OEM kernel packages in the repositories - they are merely compiled for the OEM.

Try your hardware with the current (19.10) kernel, and see if it solves your problem. If not, you can visit the [OEM kernel code repository](https://code.launchpad.net/~canonical-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem/+git/bionic/+ref/oem), pull rev 1053, and compile it yourself if you happen to have those skills. Generally, compiling it yourself should NOT be necessary. The Ubuntu kernel devs work very hard to fold new features into the stock kernel in a timely manner.

Note that the testing result page that you linked to did not indicate full compatibility with some audio hardware. Happily, almost two years later, there is a good likelihood that newer kernels may work better with that hardware.

Comment: Ah okay, I thought hardware manufacturers had responsibility for those kernels (I believe Dell compiles their own flavor of Ubuntu for their high-grade developer machines per Project Sputnik). I had 19.10 installed as the WiFi card did not work with older Ubuntu versions, but alas it does not have native microphone support. As a workaround, I'm just buying a microphone to access the 3.5mm speaker/mic port and hoping that will suffice. Marking as done.

Comment: Oh my God the microphone *mute* button light was on, I thought it was the microphone.